# how to manage users permissions in Spring OAuth2 resource owner password?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I implemented `Spring` `OAuth2` resource owner password, based mostly in 
[Dave Syer example](https://github.com/scratches/jpa-method-security-sample/).
 I am a little confused about handling user's permissions. So, for example, i've got this login request:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic cGVwZTpwZXBlc2VjcmV0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: cea7a288-3f4a-9a83-47b3-eb6cc4218cf2
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username=myusername&password=mypassword
(and client_id:client_secret encoded)
```

And it responses:

```
{
  "access_token": "2ff22411-1ec5-4a36-954f-071de576e78d",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 8918,
  "scope": "READ_FLIGHTS"
}
```

This user has scope `READ_FLIGHTS`. But that scope correspond to  `client_id`, so the user logged in that application has that scope too. I would want to specify scopes to users, not clients. Is that possible? 
For example, i want to have this `user A` which has scope `WRITE_FLIGHTS`, and an `user B` which doesn't have it. Both users inside the same application (`client_id`).

Do you know how to do that?

---

### EDIT

I've already checked [Spring Security OAuth reference](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) but i cannot finish understanding the way to implement it. If you know an example with this implementation, that would be great. I couldn't find any

Comment: I've been looking at this during this week as well. My current strategy is to implement a UserApprovalStore that modifies the scopes inside AuthorizationRequest  when checkForApproval is called. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/

Comment: @tobad357 thanks! i'm going to think about it if there isn't another solution